# at mongoDB, why .find method didn't work here while .findById worked fine?

Tags: mongodb, ejs

I'm working on project where I'm using EJS at html and mongodb as my database and NodeJS.
it supposed that when someone click on a photo for more information, he will be redirected to another page according to the ID of that photo inside database, and more information about that photo will received from database and will be passed to html.ejs file to display them, and here is the code of that:

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res){
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){
            console.log("can't find this campground");
        } else {
            res.render("show", { foundCampground: foundCampground });
        }
    });
});
```

and here is my code at HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="">
        <h2><%=foundCampground.name%></h2>
        <img src="<%=foundCampground.image%>">
        <p><%=foundCampground.describe%></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

my question is, at JS code when i use 
.findByID method, everything works fine and data will be displayed.

but if i used .find({_id: req.params.id}, function, it can't displayed anything.
i tried to checkout whether the data received from database and passed correctly to HTML file, i found that if i said like

```
<p> foundCampground </p>
```

it will display an object of all data about foundCampground, but if i used dot notation like

```
<p> foundCampground.name </p>
```

it never works, so why this happen?

Comment: Assuming you're using Mongoose, `find` provides its results as an array of documents, not a single document. Are you handling the difference?

Comment: yea.
thx for your comment, it works now

Answer (score 0):

Campground.findById() will return an object you can interate over that but

Campground.find() will return an array with foundoject as an element so to iterate you have to call foundgroup[0].name